# Content provider questions

Tags: discussion, scope

How do we feel about content provider questions, such as [Streaming video to Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5241/streaming-video-to-android)?  That one's a bit on the border -- it's useful for users to know whether they can stream video as well -- but clearly there will be some questions that aren't relevant to regular users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a similar approach as with dev questions (as discussed in [Development Questions: where to draw the line](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299/development-questions-where-to-draw-the-line)), where:

1. User questions about how they can access content is on topic
2. Advice on the "Android audience" or questions more about media tech than Android are offtopic
3. Questions such as the example in this question where it's borderline are determined on a case-by-case basis.

I personally think the example is **on** topic.

Comment: Agree, and that particular example only needs a couple of words changed and then it would be a totally on topic "How can I do XXX on my phone" type question that no one would question at all.