# How do we feel about Bluestacks?

Tags: discussion, question-appropriateness

A publicly downloadable version of the [Bluestacks Android app player](http://bluestacks.com/download.html) has recently been released for Windows. Should we accept questions related to using Bluestacks here?

On the one hand, it's not a full Android environment (no home screen, settings menu, that kind of stuff). On the other hand, it appears to be running an emulator instance under-the-hood, so you can, for example, interact with Bluestacks using `adb` and so forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emulator questions are on-topic, as are questions about android-x86, so I don't see why this wouldn't be.

It may be too early to tell.

Comment: I agree with Al, I think Bluestack questions should be fine here.

Answer (score 4):

I think the conclusions we came to about the official emulator apply here: [Questions that are on the fence between development and power use](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/questions-that-are-on-the-fence-between-development-and-power-use)

In short, I think we should support end-user questions about it.  I think this would extend to installation troubles as well, just like we do with drivers, rather than pushing them to Super User.  As Al notes, we can wait and see exactly where we feel the line should be.

Dev uses of this player should be off-topic, of course.